# Passing a point collection to visual HitTest

Tags: wpf, collections

Can I pass a collection of locations to HitTest(object, location). I have a line for an object and a points that make the edge of a shape, which are the locations. Is this an efficient way of finding the intersection point?

Comment: Instead of a collection of points for the edges of an ellipse, can't you use an `EllipseGeometry`?

Comment: @Meleak I didn't know I can pass a Geometry instead of a location to HitTest, that's what you are saying right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insead of a collection of points for the edges of an ellipse, can't you use an EllipseGeometry?

Here is an example

```
void SomeControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
    Point point = e.GetPosition(element);
    EllipseGeometry hitGeometry = new EllipseGeometry(point, 1.0, 1.0);
    VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(element,
                             null,
                             new HitTestResultCallback(HitTestCallback),
                             new GeometryHitTestParameters(hitGeometry)); 
}
public HitTestResultBehavior HitTestCallback(HitTestResult result)
{
    // Do your hit testing
}
```

Comment: @mihajlv: Any luck with the suggestion above or did it cause you any trouble?

Comment: I am about to try it today, I got stuck with some other stuff, I'll let you know as soon as I test it.

Comment: Hi Meleak, I tried it today and it shows that the two shapes have intersected, but I cannot find from this the point of intersection, relative to whatever, without this information the whole thing doesn't help me. Any ideas?

Comment: @mihajlv: Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to find the intersection area with this approach. The closest thing seems to be `IntersectionDetail` which can be either `Empty`, `FullyContains`, `FullyInside`, `Intersects` or `NotCalculated`. From the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx